# Unset frontname set by module in Magento

Tags: php, model-view-controller, magento

Magento has this very nice MVC system where modules can register their 'frontname' and the like.

Unfortunately is has the effect of contaminating your site with many duplicate urls for the same page if you happen to use several stores and make the store code show up in the URI. It will effectively make a module available on every store view 'root' and the main magento root as well.

So I want to get rid of those frontnames a module created for me. I am still using objects supplied by the module I just don't want it to use the controller it supplier as well (I built my own blocks to load relevant data).

**So my question is fairly simple,** lets say I have something like this in the community code pool module/etc/config.xml:

```
    <routers>
        <faq>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Faq</module>
                <frontName>faq</frontName>
            </args>
        </faq>
    </routers>
```

How do I make an override / setting in my local codepool that basically unsets / disables this frontname so it doesn't get found when called?

Alternatively is it possible to prevent loading controllers with frontnames on the store view roots when the option to display the code in the URI is enabled?

Comment: "undoes that frontname and doesn't use it when called" <-- this is unclear. Can you rephrase?

Comment: rephrased, I don't really know what I'm looking for, thats always nice to try and explain :p

Comment: [Profanity is not welcome here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/142838).

Comment: @meagar I am well aware.

Comment: @sg3s Then don't use it. Very simple.

Comment: @meagar I'm human, I slip up, it wasn't meant to be insultingly anyway. The edit comments are there to let me know what was changed, and why, not the question comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your point is here exactly. It sounds like you have SEO concerns (with your mention of dup. urls)

1. You've got the choice ***not*** to declare a router for your custom module
2. You could just enable canonical URLs and anything worth indexing (categories/products/cms) will have the right URL
3. You could disallow access to those URLs using robots.txt

Failing that, you could take the drastic (and seemingly pointless) approach to unset the registered route. Extending ...

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front
```

Would allow you to control the protected routes as you see fit.

Comment: 1. It's not MY module and I don't want to touch the files supplied by the community module. 2. Canonical URLS are enabled I don't know what they have to do with this 3. But they'll still be accessible by normal users; this isn't only about seo, I want to prevent trash in say google analytics. The class override seems excessive for something which should be easy.... possible though..

Comment: If you want clean URLs displayed in Anayltics, extend the analytics module to ensure it uses Mage::getUrl() with the params rewrite=true, then it will report the vanity URL to GA too. I still cannot understand your concerns through, if you NOINDEX the offending URLs, and do not link to them internally/externally - there should be no cause for concern?

Comment: These options aren't ideal by a long shot but I'll accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at core_url_rewrite table in Magento. You should be able to overwrite the urls which are set in code by modules. Its not exactly unsetting, but its one way to work around the issue.

Comment: The core_url_rewrite table is for the opposite. To translate vanity URLs into their respective namespace/module/controller.